# Delete index by alias name

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

With Elasticsearch, I can delete an index by its name:

```
DELETE my_index
{}
```

But I can not delete it by its alias name:

```
DELETE my_index_alias
{}
```

Error is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "The provided expression [my_index_alias] matches an alias, specify the corresponding concrete indices instead."
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "The provided expression [my_index_alias] matches an alias, specify the corresponding concrete indices instead."
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Is there a way to delete an index by its alias name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the thing you are trying to achieve is not possible. Currently, ElasticSearch DELETE API supports the following :

1. You may either delete an index

`curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/{indexname}'`

deletes {indexname} if and only if {indexname} is a **concrete index.**

or 2. Delete the alias instead

`curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_alias/{aliasname}'`

deletes {aliasname} if and only if {aliasname} is an **index alias.**

Comment: `curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_alias/{aliasname}'` no longer works on ES 6.X. It says: `allowed: [PUT, HEAD, GET, POST]`

Answer (score 1):

Although you cannot delete an index by alias name, you can instead make a request to the [Resolve Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-resolve-index-api.html) to give it the name of an alias. It will return all indexes associated with that alias name so you can loop through those and delete them.

You can also give it the name of an index and it will return any aliases for it.

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned says that what you are deleting using syntax `DELETE whatever_you_put_here` is actually a syntax or query *to delete an index* and suggest users that if they are looking to delete `indexes`, then it can't be done by deleting an alias.

When you create an alias say for e.g. `myalias` and you associate a sample index `myindex` to it, upon deletion of index `myindex` your alias `myalias` also gets deleted.

However when you create an alias and *associate two indices* to it, you need to *delete both the indices* for your alias to be deleted.

An empty `alias` doesn't exist in `Elasticsearch` and you cannot create it.

Note that you can check the list of aliases you have by executing the below query

```
GET /_alias
```

Now if you simply want to delete an `alias` of an `index`, you can delete it using the below `DELETE` query.

```
DELETE myindex/_alias/myalias
```

Note that if you have two indices refer to same alias, then the alias would continue to exist until you execute the above `DELETE` operation for both indexes.

> is there a way to delete an index using its alias

As for the above query, I don't think that is possible and also it doesn't make sense.